# Have C++ class manage life of Objective-C class?

Tags: c++, objective-c

Here is what I am not sure about:

I have a c++ class that will create and own an obj-C object and very simply, when that C++ class is constructed I call:

```
this->objCObject = [ThatObject new];
```

But how do I deal with destroying the ObjC object in ~MyCPPClass() ? Under ARC there is no retain/release.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [disable ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658549/95976) for the specific file that contains your CPP class. That will give you the freedom to use `retain`/`release` in your CPP class.

If you have multiple cases that need the same trick, you could look at the [`shared_ptr` for Objective-C objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8172210/95976)